# Jenkins: nested view of build metrics

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins, jobs refer to runnable tasks that are controlled and monitored by Jenkins. Build is result of one run of a job. I'd like to get a nested view of build metrics. Something similar to the following build metrics (with build metrics plugin); however, I'd like to have a hierarchical levels (i.e., nested view) of build metrics as opposed to a flat list of builds (and their metrics). How do I achieve this goal? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a multi-job project you can see the hierarchy very clearly,

So one job calls to an aggregator job which also has to be a multi-job project

And you can add the description for every section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this multijob project, how to display build metrics (or statistics such as percentage of failed builds etc.)? Thanks!